# double check Android studio in list view

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

**I have a problem developing Android application**

The project is being developed in Android Studio, with the programming language Kotlin

I was trying to implement a custom adapter to a list, however when I run the program a selection error is generated, this error is as follows:

When one of the boxes is selected, with an id *n*, if *n* is odd, all the odd boxes are marked, and it happens the same when *n* is even, all the boxes with the same id are marked.

I attach the code of the template, the view and the class that interact in the part of the program when the error is generated.

Template:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbCheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ServiciosServicioActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tViewServicio"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical">

             <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewRequisitos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="22dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="300dp" />

         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Class code:

```
class ServiciosServicioActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_servicios_servicio)

    val nombre = intent.getStringExtra("Nombre")
    val encargado = intent.getStringExtra("Encargado")
    val requisitos = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Requisitos")

    val tViewNombre = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tServicio)
    val tViewEncargado = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tEncargadoServicio)
    val lViewRequisitos = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listViewRequisitos)

    tViewNombre?.text = nombre
    tViewEncargado?.text = encargado
    val adaptador = AdaptadorCheck(this, requisitos)
    lViewRequisitos.adapter = adaptador
}
}
```

Adapter Code:

```
class AdaptadorCheck(var context: Context, items: ArrayList<String>):BaseAdapter() {
    private var items:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    init{ this.items = items }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var holder: AdaptadorCheck.ViewHolder? = null
        var vista:View? = convertView

        if(vista == null ){
            vista = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate   (R.layout.template_check, null)
            holder = AdaptadorCheck.ViewHolder(vista)
            vista.tag = holder
        }else{
            holder = vista.tag as? AdaptadorCheck.ViewHolder
        }

        val item = getItem(position) as String
        holder?.nombre?.text = item

        return vista!!
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return items?.get(position)!!
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return items?.count()!!
    }

    private class  ViewHolder(vista: View){
        var nombre: CheckBox? = null
        init{
            nombre = vista.findViewById(R.id.cbCheck)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post custom adapter code as well.

Comment: It's done
I'm sorry for that mistake @Ranjan

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: yes, i implement other solution, but i still need help to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried exact same code and I found out the problem. To understand it, you'll have to first understand how `listView` works. From the documentation -

> ListView attempts to reuse view objects in order to improve
>   performance and avoid a lag in response to user scrolls.
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView

Problem with your code is that your `listview's` height is `wrap_content` and because of that only 1 view is visible. So when you scroll down, listView reuse view from the top. So when you come to 3rd view, `listView` reuse view at position 1 and since your `checkbox` is reused, it shows as if 3rd view's `checkbox` was already checked.

Few things I would suggest.

- When you are going to take input from user in a list, you'll have to store it somewhere in an local array, so that you can retrieve those values again. Otherwise they'll just get lost when user scrolls.
- You can make an array which stores boolean values and depending on boolean value you'll update your `checkbox`. Also update this array when user changes value of any `checkbox`. *It should work vice versa. Showing latest state of `checkbox` from the array and updating the array when `checkbox` is selected/unselected. This you'll do in `getView` method of `adapter`.*
- Also I have never seen anyone use `wrap_content` over a listView. Probably you are trying to something else and not finding the right `View` to do it.
- You can try changing the width of `listView` and see that there is nothing wrong with your code.
- Go for `recyclerView` instead. It is an improvement to `listView`.